# Missing type, but seems to really be a version mismatch

Tags: .net, reference, dllimport, dll

I am getting this error message when I compile my .NET 4.0 app.:

> The type 'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

The class it says it needs is defined when you add System to the project references.

It seems to be saying that it needs a version 3 reference.  I am not sure what to do.

If anyone has an idea I would love to hear it.

As a side note, I am using the TFS API and this code:

```
// Get the id of the work item that we got from the server (or the work item associated with it)
int workItemId;

// If this is a test run then we need to look up the work item it is running off of
if (notificationEventArgs is TestCaseResultChangedNotification)
{
    TestCaseResultChangedNotification testCaseResultChangedNotification = (notificationEventArgs as TestCaseResultChangedNotification);
    ITestManagementTeamProject testManagementTeamProject = TFSAccess.Instance.TestManagement.GetTeamProject(testCaseResultChangedNotification.ProjectName);
    ITestCaseResult testCaseResult = testManagementTeamProject.TestResults.Find(testCaseResultChangedNotification.TestCaseResultIdentifier.TestRunId, testCaseResultChangedNotification.TestCaseResultIdentifier.TestResultId);
    workItemId = testCaseResult.TestCaseId;

    foreach (ITestIterationResult testIterationResult in testCaseResult.Iterations)
    {

    }
}
```

It is the Iterations collection that is causing the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So did you try to add a reference to WindowsBase version 4?  It contains a [TypeForwardedTo] attribute to redirect the INotifyCollectionchanged type to System.dll.  That should take care of it.

Comment: So what did you actually do to fix this issue?

Comment: He added a reference to WindowsBase.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 3.0 `ObservableCollection` was defined in `WindowsBase` assembly. In .NET 4.0 it is defined in `System`. It seems that TFS API targets v3.0...

Either retarget your project to earlier version or reference WindowsBase. In second case you may need to use the approach described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx).